# using dynamic_rnn with multiRNN gives error

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create a dynamic_rnn using tensorflow in python with Multi LSTM cells.
form searches on internet I have found this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 30
truncated_series_length = 4
num_layers = 3
state_size = 300

x_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_series_length, 1])


cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_input, dtype=tf.float32)
```

but when I run this code an error happens:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 600 and 301 for 'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/lstm_cell/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [30,600], [301,1200].

but when I set num_layers = 1, there isn't any error.
do you have any idea that where this error come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is roughly addressed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16186

Basically, to elaborate the answer from this issue: 
Using `[cell]*num_layers` will create a list of two references to the same cell instance but not two separate instances. The correct behavior is that the LSTM cell at first layer should have weight shape like (dimensionality_of_feature + cell_state_size, 4*cell_state_size).
And the LSTM cells at consecutive layers should have weight shape like (2*cell_state_size, 4*cell_state_size).  Because they no longer take original input but the input from the previous layer.

But the problem in the shared reference code is that for both layers they will use the same kernel due to "they" are actually the same cell instance. Therefore, even if you have more than one layers, all layers except the first one will have the wrong shape of weight (always referring to the weight of the first layer).

A better code as indicated in this issue is using list comprehension or for loop to create multiple separate instances to avoid sharing references.

Answer (score 0):

same error happened when I run the code as follows: 

`one_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=rnn_size) 
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([one_cell for _ in range(num_layers)]) # same as [one_cell]*num_layers ?`

But when I run the following code, this error disappeared.

`cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=rnn_size) for _ in range(num_layers)])`

So I think the operation `[one_cell for _ in range(num_layers)]`and `[one_cell]*num_layers` will keep all cells same settings. But we want the first layer cell has different settings with the other layer cells.